# Powershell script to table doesn't output anything

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a simple script to ping the various servers in my (home) network.

Because I want to output into a nice Powershell table, I'm defining my own output function. However, the output currently is empty:

```
@{Address=; IPv4=}
@{Address=; IPv4=}
@{Address=; IPv4=}
```

The question is why, because the servers exist, and if I run just a Test-Connection I do get output:

```
Test-Connection $server -Count 1

Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address   ...etc
------        -----------     -----------      -----------
DESKTOP...    server3         99.99.999.201
```

**Question 1:** What am I doing wrong?

```
While (1)
{
    Foreach ($server in "server1","server2","server3")
    {
        $test = Test-Connection $server -Count 1

        Output $test
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
}


Function Output($input)
{
    $output = New-Object psobject

    $output | Add-Member noteproperty Address $input.Address
    $output | Add-Member noteproperty IPv4    $input.IPV4Address

    Write-Host $Output
}
```

**Question 2:** I am now defining the servers to ping manually. Is there a way to just scan the network / give in IP-range and automagically ping every server in it?

Comment: As for your second question (which should've been a separate question): `0..254 | ForEach-Object { Test-Connection "192.168.1.$_" -Count 1 }`

Comment: It is not a duplicate, as changing `$input` into any other variable name does not solve the issue

Comment: I seriously doubt that (because I actually tested it before closing the question). Please provide evidence.